# Problema ao capturar valor de objeto

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou realizando uma pesquisa no banco de dados (mongoDB) dessa forma ele me retorna uma array, eu queria apenas estar pegando um objeto da array mas não estou conseguindo.

```
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
        Gift.find().lean().then(gifts =>{
            res.render("loja/index", {gifts: gifts})
            console.log(gifts._id)
        })
    })
```

Consegui estar capturando o tal valor utilizando apenas o findOne, nesse caso, oque exatamente eu teria que estar realizando para que pudesse estar capturando todos os _id dos meus documentos?

Answer (score 0):

Para obter os `_id` dos seus dados basta fazer a pesquisa usando o `.find()` ou `distinct`. Existem diferente formas para retornar a informação como você gostaria além destas que estou citando, pois o `_id` já vem por padrão em todas as consultas que fazemos no MongoDB.

Para este caso recomendo a utilização do `distinct` desta forma:

```
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    Gift.distinct('_id', {}).lean().then(gifts =>{
      res.render("loja/index", {gifts: gifts})
      console.log(gifts)
    })
})
```

Ou utilizando o Async/Await

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  try{
    const gifts = await Gifts.distinct('_id', {})
    return res.render('/loja/index', { gifts })
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

Comment: Compreendi, no caso, pelo que eu entendi o `distinct` retorna valores distintos dos campos, ou seja, o gifts._id foi um exemplo, mas caso eu queria estar pegando o valor de gifts.valor para assim realizar uma soma de tais, isso não se encaixaria, pelo fato de poder conter vários objetos com o mesmo valor, pelo que compreendi seria basicamente isso que ocorre, me corrija se estiver errado nessa questão.

Comment: Sim, ele trará apenas os campos selecionados, até onde pude perceber era isso que você queria. Dê uma olhada nesta respostas [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find).